# Custom ListViewItem in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, user-controls

possible ways to show item in ListViewItem **WPF**

**Update:**
[image]

that's the control i need to add to the ListView, in here i only need to display the Computer Name, still the item should hold the Computer Address

[image]

later, i will need ListView with Items that represent Files and Folders which will have : Name, Path, Size, Icon, IsFile properties.

so this's what I'm dealing with right now, im stuck in listView which i didn't expect to happen when i switched to WPF

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What do you want that for? Use a regular `ListViewItem`.

Comment: I'm sorry, you have no idea what you're talking about. What are you trying to do? BTW, **Don't manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF, that's what XAML is for**.

Comment: @HighCore if you think so, I'm working on `listView` as file Explorer, and `listViewItem` as a File item, I need to add Name,Size,Path,IsFile,Image to each item, and that makes it more complicated than creating a `userControl` which only misses `IsSelected` property! so what do you think?

Comment: Just add additional Columns to the GridView. I don't see what the big difficulty is

Comment: @HighCore You don't get it, I've already been threw all that, and when i get it done with `ListViewItem` and i override it to add more properties, but my problem was that i couldn't be able to assign the extra properties to my custom `ListViewItem Style`. There are no much articles and questions about it, and everyone is using more complex way than the other. I believe using `userControl` is more suitable for this case.

Comment: I am with HighCore.  What do you need that a GridView with a checkbox column bound to a property IsSelected would not do?

Comment: @MurHaf `You don't get it` - Yes I get it perfectly. You're trying to use WPF as if it were winforms. **IT IS NOT**. Learn WPF properly and forget winforms.

Comment: @HighCore alright let it be `ListViewItem`, what about adding new properties which are not existed in regular `listViewItem`, do you have a solution?

Comment: It's called 'Attached Property'.  You can read about if you ever decide to take up WPF

Comment: @Blam `ListViewItem` Already have `IsSelected` property, why would i need a checkbox column for!

Comment: @MurHaf You DONT NEED to add properties in the UI to hold Data. UI is not Data. Please learn that. Please post a screenshot of what you need  so we can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore here you go

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is another example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button Content="Show Selected Computer" Click="Button_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComputer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel Margin="2">
                        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Width="32" Height="32" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = Enumerable.Range(1,10)
                                .Select(x => new ComputerInfo()
                                {
                                    Name = "Computer" + x.ToString(),
                                    Ip = "192.168.1." + x.ToString()
                                });

    }

    public ComputerInfo SelectedComputer { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(SelectedComputer.Ip);
    }
}
```

Data Item:

```
public class ComputerInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, both of the answers are important to me, thanks again i will do it this way

Comment: @Murhaf I Suggest you read [This Tutorial](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) on how to create "Items"-based UIs in WPF.

Answer (score 6):

Look dude, I made a simple "File Explorer" example in a couple of lines of XAML in 5 minutes.

There is NO need to create your own `ListViewItem` or anything like that. WPF is NOT winforms. You need to understand this.

[I already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20498876/643085) this to you. [UI is Not Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085).

Look:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication14"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Size">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Size" Text="{Binding Size}"/>
                            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFile}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Size" Property="Text" Value="[Directory]"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Path" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var path = @"C:\";

        var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                            .Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x))
                            .Select(x => new FileViewModel()
                            {
                                Name = x.Name,
                                Path = x.FullName,
                                IsFile = false,

                            });

        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path)
                               .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
                               .Select(x => new FileViewModel()
                               {
                                   Name = x.Name,
                                   Path = x.FullName,
                                   Size = x.Length,
                                   IsFile = true,
                               });


       DataContext = dirs.Concat(files).ToList();

    }
}
```

Data Item:

```
public class FileViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public bool IsFile { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Do you see? There is no need to overcomplicate anything. WPF has everything you need to do anything.