# creating Icon View mode for ListView WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I'm Trying to change `listView` GridView to IconView, as you see in the screenshot, each item is taking a row.

[image]

**Style XAML**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style x:Key="FileItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Width="50">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2.5"/>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**ListView XAML**

```
    <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource FileItemStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="194.667" Margin="11,77.666,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="368.667" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" UseLayoutRounding="False">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" CornerRadius="2.5"/>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image x:Name="Img" Source="BtnImg/Computer.png" Stretch="None" Margin="9,0,9,0" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="PCName" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center"><Run Text="{Binding Content}"/></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBoxItem Content="ddd"/>  <!--**-->
        <ListViewItem Content="zczxcz"/>
    </ListView>
```

I've tried to use [MDSN example : How to: Create a Custom View Mode for a ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748859.aspx) and modify it to get what I need, but it didn't work with me, I actually couldn't understand the example clearly, anyone can Simplify how can I create a View mode? Do I have to create an overrided ViewBase class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're mixing `ListView`, and `ListBox`, remove the `ListView` and use `ListBox`-specific XAML.

Comment: @HighCore Ok I've changed everything to `ListView` and `ListViewItem`, now the style lost, but check this http://postimg.org/image/cueewkt4l/
Why is this happening?

Comment: @HighCore also I changed all of them to `ListBox` and `ListBoxItem` the style is lost too

Comment: post your current XAML, with these changes you mention

Comment: @HighCore done, but here's the screenshot http://postimg.org/image/cueewkt4l/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the same exact Code Behind as [My Answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20531263/643085):

```
 <Style x:Key="FileItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" >
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2.5"/>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComputer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FileItemStyle}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Rectangle Height="32" Width="32" Fill="Blue"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Result:

[image]

- Remove the hardcoded `Width` and `Height`s
- Replace the blue rectangle for your Image.
- Add some Triggers in the `ControlTemplate` so that you get highlighting when `IsSelected="True"`
- Simply change the [`ItemsPanel`](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/02/10/itemscontrol-p-is-for-panel/) of any `ItemsControl` in order to define how items are laid out.
- Using a [`WrapPanel`](http://wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html), you get a layout similar to Windows Explorer, where items are placed horizontally until there is no more horizontal space and then another "row" is created. Run the example and resize the Window to see this.

---

Bottom line: NO, you don't need custom code to customize the UI in WPF. It can be done with the existing controls and some XAML. Please read the ["Alternatives to Writing a New Control"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#when_to_write_a_new_control) section in [MSDN: Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: damnit HC, I was just sitting there typing out to change the ItemsPanel... +1

Comment: You are WPF Encyclopedia

Comment: one more question, I used `TextWrapping="Wrap"` for the `textBlock` to force it to resize itself when the text need more space, I want the Item "height" resize with it, to make sure textBlock is shown, what should i do?

Comment: @MurHaf The `Grid` inside the `ListViewItem` template (in the style) has a hardcoded `Height="50"`. Remove that and it will be auto-sized to the contents.

Comment: @MurHaf it's also much more visually elegant if you use `TextAlignment="Center"` on the `TextBlock`.